# How to put domain instead of app ID when Screensharing in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, screensharing

My Chrome App has been verified and approved.

I have implemented Screen Share functionality.

I want to show my domain instead of the app ID. See the below Image for reference.

**My Current App: Shows APP ID**

[image]

**I want to achieve something like this:**

[image]

How do I change it?

Comment: The point of this message is to inform the user about the origin of the code which is accessing their screen content. In your case, code in your app is accessing the screen; in the second case, code running on meet.google.com is accessing the screen content. This is a matter of letting the user know whom they are trusting with their screen content. If you want it to show a different origin, you need to have the user execute the screen-sharing code on a page from that origin.

Comment: Possibly you could migrate your screen-sharing code out of your app onto a page on your domain, and make your app navigate a new tab to that page? But I'm not sure what apps vs. extensions can/can't do with regard to opening new pages.